# Difference between in ""," " in python

Tags: python, loops

what is the difference between "" and " " because

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6-i):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i):
        print(i,"",end="")
    print()
```

gives

[image]

and

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6-i):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i):
        print(i," ",end="")
    print()
```

gives

[image]

and

```
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6-i):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i):
        print(i,end="")
    print()
```

gives

[image]

***I wanted to know the difference "" and " " because "" also gives some space***

Comment: 2nd example having 2 spaces.. an 1st having 1 space

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 1):

the behavior from your 3 examples it is given by the built-in function [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), the default `sep=' '` as you can see in the docs, this means that even if you have an empty string `""` in 3 consecutive items you will have 2 spaces in the output when you print them, having the one in the middle the empty  string will give you the impression (at the output) that there are 2 spaces between 2 consecutive items; printing 3 elements with the one in the middle as the space character  `" "` will give your the impression that between 2 consecutive elements there are 3 spaces

```
print(i, "", 1)
```

output:

```
5  1 # 5+sep_1space+the_empthy_string+sep_1space+1
print(i," ", 1)
```

output:

```
5   1 # 5+sep_1space+1space+sep_1space+1
print(i,1)
```

output:

```
5 1 # 5+sep_1space+1
```